# Invoking program from command line

Tags: java, eclipse, terminal

I have a class like this from Algorithms class:

```
public class Counter {
    private final String name;
    private int count;

    public Counter(String id) {
        name = id;
    }

    public void increment(){
        count++;
    }

    public int tally(){
        return count;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return count + " " + name;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter heads = new Counter("heads");
        Counter tails = new Counter("tails");
        heads.increment();
        heads.increment();
        tails.increment();

        StdOut.println(heads + " " + tails); 
        StdOut.println(heads.tally() - tails.tally());
    }
}
```

When I run it in Eclipse it works fine but when I invoke it in terminal with:

```
java -cp '../jar/algs4.jar:../jar/stdlib.jar' Counter
```

it returns

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at Counter.main(Counter.java:79)
```

Why is that?

Comment: Try adding `.:` to the beginning of the class path?

Comment: Where's line 79? There is an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` there.

Comment: Thanks Ismail , that solved it. Why do I need to add current dir to classpath?

Comment: @jasonD I fear this may be only masking the real problem. It looks like you have two copies of your program on the classpath now - a new copy, which works, and an old copy, which doesn't work.

Comment: @jasonD If you specify a classpath with `-cp`, the current directory isn't included by default. Usually you'd get an error about not being able to find the class, but I guess there must be a class also called `Counter` in one of those jars.